# Show/hide function toggle for iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, toggle

I have a function toggle on my website ***([example is here](http://www.einstruktor.pl/szukaj/))*** where you can **show and hide** text within DIV. Code:

.js code

```
function toggle(sDivId) {
                var oDiv = document.getElementById(sDivId);
                oDiv.style.display = (oDiv.style.display == "none") ? "block" : "none";
}
```

.html code:

```
<div onclick="toggle('divContent1')" style="cursor: pointer;">Hide and show</div>
    <div id="divContent1" style='display:none'>
    text here
    </div>
</div>
```

This function is working fine on the website when I browse it on my computer. But when I checked my website **on iPad it doesn`t work**. Does anyone know **why** and could you **suggest the solution** for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You have added JQuery as a tag, but are not using JQuery at all. Why not? This code is much simpler in jQuery (and cross browser issues are then covered).

Comment: Could you please give me an example of jQuery code for this case? Thanks!

Comment: +1 for providing code and HTML sample. I have updated answer with cleaner version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery example:

### Html

```
<div>
    <div id="pressMe" style="cursor: pointer;">Hide and show</div>
    <div id="divContent1" style='display:none'>text here</div>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$('#pressMe').click(function(){
    $('#divContent1').toggle();
});
```

### JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cuDp5/

Play around with it on JSFiddle. You can still call functions from the click handler of the specific div if you want, this just shows an alternative. It is usually better to drive the selection of button and target using classes (to identify the buttons) and attributes like `data-targetdiv="#divContent1"` so that the code is reusable and not hard-wired to specific id's in the code.

### Example of more flexible data-driven version: http://jsfiddle.net/cuDp5/2/

Note that you need to wrap your JQuery in a "onloaded" event. In JQuery that used to be `$(document).ready(` but the modern shorthand is now just `$(function(){...});`

e.g.

```
$(function(){
   $('.pressMe').click(function(){
      $($(this).attr('data-target')).toggle();
   });
});
```

This code fetches a data attribute from the clicked item to use as the selector for which item to toggle. Much better than hard-wiring id's into the code. The example has two sets of divs to demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It`s very clear to me but when I put this code on my website (to jQuery.js and .php files) it doesn`t work at all. You may take a look: http://www.einstruktor.pl/szukaj/ Do you have any idea why it doesn`t work. Did I do something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I found this example: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UpX3L/ and it is working on my website. But thank you very much for your help - it gave me a clue and helped me to solve my problem. Have a nice day! :)

Comment: Sorry I should have explained that JSFiddle hides the `$(document).ready(` so you need to add that yourself.

Comment: No problem :) I`m new here so I`m learning how this website works :)

Comment: `$(document).ready(` is the old way of doing it. Check out the updated example.